# Nvidia-drivers problem in Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bits

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

Today I've upgraded the system and the problem is that it appears and 640*480 screen with the login and the background, after logging in, the screen got stuck.

I have an NVIDIA card, GT610 to be precise, and I have CUDA installed, this is necessary because I'm learning to develop on this. So I followed the CUDA Ubuntu 14.04 Official Instructions. Which are to install a deb package, and then do sudo apt-get install cuda. This installs nvidia-340 and cuda-6.5

Everything was fine until the upgrade, what can I do to fix this?

PS1: I've been looking for answers(reinstall ubuntu-desktop, reinstall unity), and no one seems to fix the problem.

PS2: I have a PC Intel Core i7-3770 .40 GHz, 4 GB RAM, NVIDIA GT610.

EDIT 1: There was another update today, I tried it, I repeated the uninstall-install and nothing happened

Comment: I *did* notice that you installed the cuda & nvidia-340 packages, did you install those via the xorg-edgers PPA? If you haven't, try adding the sort-edgers PPA via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` then running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`. This should allow you to install the newest version of the nvidia-340 drivers. Normally, this is a last resort measure, but you appear to have tried everything else

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness the packages are from the nvidia package (.deb) that they ask you to install here [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb). I've read that the xorg-edgers caused some "pain" in some configs from other people in other posts, so that's why I haven't tried that option.

Comment: Yeah, they can cause problems. However, if you're not getting the .deb directly from NVIDIA to work, then the only option you're really left with is the Xorg-Edgers PPA option :(

Answer (score 0):

*When you say upgrade, can I assume you mean Ubuntu updates (including kernel)?*

***Then try ..***

Purge installed Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then check which Nvidia drivers are available:

```
sudo apt-cache search "NVIDIA binary driver"
```

And re-install: eg. **340** (*your previous choice*)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I meant updates including kernel :).

I'll try this and I will tell you if it works or not.